# SPARQL query with COUNT and ORDER returns odd result

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, sparql

The following query counts all triples in a store

```
SELECT count(*) where { ?s ?p <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Cat> }
```

And returns the expected results

[http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=select+count(*)+{+%3Fs+%3Fp+%3Chttp://dbpedia.org/resource/Cat%3E+}+&debug=on&timeout=&format=text/html&save=display&fname=](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=select%20count%28%2a%29%20%7B%20?s%20?p%20%3Chttp://dbpedia.org/resource/Cat%3E%20%7D%20&debug=on&timeout=&format=text/html&save=display&fname=)

However, when I first tried it I accidentally left in an ORDER BY statement, e.g.,

```
select count(*) { ?s ?p <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Cat> } order by ?s
```

Then I get a very long list of results

[http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=select+count(*)+{+%3Fs+%3Fp+%3Chttp://dbpedia.org/resource/Cat%3E+}+order+by+%3Fs&debug=on&timeout=&format=text/html&save=display&fname=](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=select%20count%28%2a%29%20%7B%20?s%20?p%20%3Chttp://dbpedia.org/resource/Cat%3E%20%7D%20order%20by%20?s&debug=on&timeout=&format=text/html&save=display&fname=)

Can anyone explain why this result happens and what it means? Is it maybe a bug with the Virtuoso SPARQL implementation?

Comment: consider asking at semanticoverflow.com

Comment: OK, it does seem to be a Virtuoso bug, thanks for your help

Answer (score 8):

It does look like a bug, if you run the same type of queries on a different store, i.e on
http://api.talis.com/stores/bbc-backstage/services/sparql (which doesn't run virtuoso)

This first query works ...

```
SELECT (count(?s) as ?c)
WHERE {
?s ?p <http://purl.org/ontology/po/Version> .
}
```

and the second ...

```
SELECT (count(?s) as ?c)
WHERE {
?s ?p <http://purl.org/ontology/po/Version> .
} order by ?s
```

... gives the same result.

Actually counting + ordering doesn't make much sense here because `?s` is not selected to be retrieved. But as you said, you tried it accidentally and ... it does look like a bug.

My recommendation is to send an email to the [virtuoso-user mailing list](http://www.openlinksw.com/dataspace/dav/wiki/Main/VOSMailingLists) to notify about this issue.

Answer (score 3):

We (= OpenLink) are in trouble here. This ORDER BY ?s is formally a bug in the query: an aggregate without grouping means "aggregate on everything", there should be no variables outside aggregates at the output end of the query. However this error is not reported now: violations of this rule are so numerous that SQL compiler makes an auto-grouping and our SPARQL-to-SQL preprocessor also ignores this error if possible.

We will probably keep the current behaviour as is. If a "strict" compilation mode is added it will trigger the error reporting in cases like this.

Answer (score 2):

This may be a bug with Virtuoso, it seems to treat queries with aggregates and an `ORDER BY` clause as having an implicit `GROUP BY` clause.  I've noticed this on other Virtuoso endpoints besides the DBPedia one.

IMO this is a bug and you should report it to the Virutoso users mailing list as msalvadores suggests